# If DV and IV were already in percent even before log transformation, how will the log-log betas be interpreted?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, interpretation, logarithm

I have a question about the interpretation of log-log form when both left and right side variables are already in percentage to begin with even before the log transformation. For example:

Let's say that our variables in a time series regression are as follows:

DV = growth rate of GDP (%) IV = growth rate of population (%)

Let's also say that to achieve linearity (or residual normality), we have to log-transform both. Since, the both DV and IV were already in percent even before log transformation, how will the log-log betas be interpreted? My intuition is that it will be interpreted as if it were done in the lin-lin form. Is this correct? Anyone who could comment on this?

Comment: One reaction would be to question why you use logarithms, because that precludes ever fitting a negative growth rate, which in the long run will be unrealistic.